# Django Redis set max connections

Tags: python, django, redis

I'm using Django and having issues exceeding my max number of redis connections. The library I'm using is:

https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache

Here is my settings.py file:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': "pub-redis-11905.us-east-1-3.1.ec2.garantiadata.com:11905",
        'OPTIONS': {
            'DB' : 0,
            'PASSWORD': "*****",
            'PARSER_CLASS': 'redis.connection.HiredisParser'
        },
    },
}
```

Then i another file, I do some direct cache access like so:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
def getResults(self, key):
    return cache.get(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Looks like](https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache/issues/54) this is an outstanding issue with `django-redis-cache` - perhaps you should consider a different Redis cache backend for Django that does support connection pooling.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [django-redis-cache using connection-pool](http://django-redis-cache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_configuration.html#connection-pool) set max_connections.

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'OPTIONS': {
        'CONNECTION_POOL_CLASS': 'redis.BlockingConnectionPool',
        'CONNECTION_POOL_CLASS_KWARGS': {
            'max_connections': 50,
            'timeout': 20,
            ...
           },
        ...
       },
    ...
   }
}
```